# Publishing app on Japanese AppExchange

Tags: appexchange

I want to publish an app on the Japanese appexchange. Could someone guide what would be the steps required for it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the same way that publishing an application at English. The only difference is "market place".
http://www.slideshare.net/partnerforce/publish-your-first-app-on-the-appexchange/61

Other references.

[How to Transform Your Idea into an App on AppExchange](http://www.slideshare.net/Salesforce/how-to-transform-your-idea-into-an-app-on-appexchange)

[ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_intro.htm)

[ISVforce ガイド](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.ja-jp.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_intro.htm)

[アプリを開発・公開する](http://www.salesforce.com/jp/partners/isv_partners3.jsp)